# On seventh powers $x_1^7+x_2^7+\dots+x_n^7 = 2$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

We have,

$$(-6m^3 + 1)^3 + (6m^3 + 1)^3 + (-6m^2)^3 = 2$$

$$(-8m^5 + 1)^5 + (8m^5 + 1)^5 + (-8m^6 + 2m)^5 + (-8m^6 - 2m)^5 + 2(8m^6)^5=2$$

The first identity has been long known, while the second is by Ajai Choudhry. Anybody knows if there is anything similar for 7th powers?

Comment: Are you assuming we know what $m$ is?

Comment: Did you check https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/?

Comment: @Ethan, Did you look at my last name?  :)

Comment: That was the joke

Comment: Ah, good to know people here have a sense of humor.   :)

Comment: Expand
$$(a_0m^7+b_0)^7+ (a_1m^8+b_1m)^7+(a_2m^9+b_2m^2)^7+\ldots +(a_5m^{12}+b_5m^5)^7+(a_6m^{12})^7$$
to obtain conditions on the $a_i,b_i$ per power of $m$:
$$\tag{$m^0$} b_0^7=1\implies b_0=1$$
$$\tag{$m^7$} 7a_0b_0^6+b_1^7=0$$
$$\tag{$m^{14}$} 21a_0^2b_0^5+7a_1b_1^6+b_2^7=0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\tag{$m^{77}$} a_4^7+7a_6^6b_5=0$$
$$\tag{$m^{84}$} a_5^7+a_6^7=0\implies a_6=-a_5$$
and see if you find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can do is in terms of the radical $\sqrt{3}$:

$$2=(9 m^7 + 1)^7 + (-9 m^7 + 1)^7 + (\sqrt{3} m - 9 m^8)^7 + (-\sqrt{3} m - 
    9 m^8)^7 + 2 (9 m^8)^7$$

Comment: Oh, I see. You used the form $(a m^7 + 1)^7 + (-a m^7 + 1)^7 + (-a m^8 + b m)^7 + (-a m^8 - b m)^7 + 
  2(a m^8)^7 = 2$, collected powers of $m$, and found it was satisfied by $a,b = 9,\sqrt{3}$. It would have been nicer if $a,b$ were rational though.